# how to echo in PHP like this

Tags: php, html

how to echo in PHP like this...

index.php

```
$themeData = array();
$themeData['test_in_other_page'] = 'work';
```

mypage.php

```
{{TEST_IN_OTHER_PAGE}}
```

Comment: Use a template engine like twig or mustache or whatever....

Comment: Yeah like @n00dl3 says to achieve something like that you need a templating engine, have you got anymore information as this is a bit vague to be honest...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

1: get the content of mypage.php

```
$fileStr = file_get_contents('<path>/mypage.php');
```

2: replace items

```
foreach ($themeData as $name => $content)
{
  $fileStr = str_replace('{{'.$name.'}}',$content,$fileStr);
}
```

3: echo that:

```
echo $fileStr;
```

This all under the assumption I understand your question. But a templating engine would be far more flexible.